# Parsing JSON in Dart

Tags: json, parsing, dart

I'm trying to parse JSON to an object in Dart, the documentation uses *Map* type to parse a JSON response.

regarding to their documentation [Using Dart with JSON Web Services: Parsing JSON](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/json-web-service/)
,I snipped the following example:

```
import 'dart:convert';

main() {
  String mapAsJson = '{"language":"dart"}';  // input Map of data
  Map parsedMap = JSON.decode(mapAsJson);
  print(parsedMap["language"]); // dart
}
```

I applied the same in my testApp, however it didn't work

```
test() {
  var url = "http://localhost/wptest/wp-json/wp/v2/posts";

  // call the web server asynchronously
  var request = HttpRequest.getString(url).then(onDataLoaded);
}

onDataLoaded(String responseText) {
  Map x = JSON.decode(responseText);
  print(x['title'].toString());
}
```

I'm getting this error

```
Exception: Uncaught Error: type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map' of 'x'.
Stack Trace:
  post.post (package:untitled8/wp/posts.dart:25:24)
  onDataLoaded (http://localhost:63342/untitled8/web/index.dart:24:15)
  _RootZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1166)
  _Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:494)
  _Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:577)
  _Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:368)
  _Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:422)
  _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43)
  _microtaskLoopEntry (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52)
  _ScheduleImmediateHelper._handleMutation (dart:html:42567)
```

Comment: Does your JSON file start with an array?

Comment: @stevenupton yes the error was because my JSON was a list. I will post the answer in minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is correct.

```
//if JSON is an array (starts with '[' )

List<Map> x = JSON.decode(responseText);
print(x[0]['title']);

//if JSON is not an array (starts with '{' )

Map z = JSON.decode(responseText);
print(z['content']);
print(z['id']);
print(z['title']);
```

Answer (score 2):

The JSON coming from the sever need to be decoded to a json in dart and assigned to a map of type **String** and **dynamic**

The *keys* in the **json** have to **String** while their **value pair** has to be of type **dynamic** in other to hold any value be it an array or int or bool

```
  Map<String,dynamic> z = Map<String,dynamic>.from(JSON.decode(responseText));
    
    
    print(z.toString())
```

Comment: Please add further explanation to your answer to assist readers. Code only answers are not always helpful.