# Select Data from Json String in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a JSON string like this :

```
{
    "message": "Login successful",
    "result": [
        {
            "_id": "60ed65f6cb33920004c3117a",
            "username": "ajay",
        }
    ]
}
```

I Convert above string in **jsondecode(response.body)** format using flutter I got below string

```
    {
       message: Login successful, 
       result:[
          { 
             _id: 60ed65f6cb33920004c3117a,
             username: ajay
          }
       ]
   }
```

I Can find _id and username of result section when user logged in successfully

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing JSON in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33581947/parsing-json-in-dart)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use string indexes to access these properties:

```dart
print(object['result'][0]['_id']);        // 60ed65f6cb33920004c3117a
print(object['result'][0]['username']);   // ajay
```

Now this is not ideal, and if you have many such objects it's probably worth it to use a model class and serialize your JSON into that, as highlighted in the Flutter documentation:

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-inside-model-classes

#### Extra link

The documentation also refers to the cookbook for a more complete and comprehensive example of using such model classes:

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/background-parsing

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the following code snippet, you will get your results on var id and username:

```
var id;
var username;

var resp = jsonDecode(response.body);

id = resp['result'][0]['_id'];
username = resp['result'][0]['username'];
```