# Convert a JSObject to being readable in Dart

Tags: javascript, dart, google-chrome, dart-html

This is a repeat of several similar questions, but all of the answers I've seen are 7-10+ years old an no longer relevant, as dart has since come out with null safety.

Currently, I am building a Chrome Web Extension in Dart and using some Dart interop libraries like the `package:js/js.dart` and `dart:js`. I am trying to retrieve a key-value pair from the Chrome Storage API, and can successfully do that with the following:

```
var test = context['chrome']['storage']['local'];
test.callMethod('get', [
  ['r'], // Assume that this is already stored in chrome storage via chrome.storage.local.set()
  (Object result) {
    _getCallback(result);
  }
]);

void _getCallback(dynamic stuff) {
  JsObject obj = stuff as JsObject;
  print(obj.toString());
}
```

The issue is that I am unable to see anything inside of `obj`, as it just returns a `JsObject` type. Is there a proper way in modern dart to retrieve what i need from this object? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert it to a [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)
(JavaScript Object Notation) string

```
JSON.strigify(object)   // Javascript
```

save the string in the storage and then retrive it from the storage and parse it from Dart

```
import 'dart:convert';  // Dart

JSON.decode(string)
```

---

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55878148/13181643) *may* help for parsing the JSON from dart.

Comment: Probably a noob question here, but `JSON` is not coming up as a valid anything for me. Is this from the `dart:convert` package?

Comment: No, from `dart:convert` you'll only get the Dart class needed in order to decode a JSON string. JSON is a language-independent. I've updated the answer with a link to JSON definition. You may find it useful. Basycally a javascript object can be stringified into a JSON string (i.e `{prop: 'value'}` in javascript became `'{"prop": "value"}'`, and can be sent and parsed easily).

Comment: Ohhhh i see what youre saying now. Thanks!